# Onchange functionality is not working in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Onchange functionality is working properly while pageloading and if the user keeps on changing the values it shows error.Whats the root cause?

```
    <aura:attribute name="Components" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Components1" type="List"/>

    <aura:handler name="deleteJob" event="c:deleteJobEvt" action="{!c.RemoveClick}" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <p>
        <center><h5><b>Creating Action Criteria </b></h5></center>
    </p>
    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">
        <b>
            <I> Action Criteria</I>
        </b>
    </h3>
    <table >
        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
            <th class="head">
                <I>Action</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Object Name</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Component</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Operator</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator * Value</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator / Value</I>
            </th>
        </tr>

    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.wrplst.length > 0}">
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a">
                <c:NewAction wrp="{!a}" options="{!v.options}" Components="{!v.Components}"  Components1="{!v.Components1}" selectedValue=""  idval="{!v.theId}"/>

        </aura:iteration>
        </aura:renderIf>
    </table>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Add row" onclick="{!c.AddRow}" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand"  label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveRow}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Javascript**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
         helper.pageLoad(component);
         helper.componentVal(component);

     },
     doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
         helper.Method2(component);
     },
     RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {
         var selCont = event.getParam("selectedJob");
         var conts = component.get("v.wrplst");
         var contsval = JSON.stringify(conts);
         var Selndex = conts.indexOf(selCont);
         var DeleteLen = conts.length;
         //alert('deleteLen value::::' + DeleteLen);
         var removeAction = component.get("c.removeRow");
         removeAction.setParams({
             "wrvalue": contsval,
             "rowval": Selndex
         });
         removeAction.setCallback(this, function(g) {
             var state = g.getState();
             if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                 alert('success value');
                 component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
             } else if (state === 'error') {
                 alert('error value');
             }
         });
         $A.enqueueAction(removeAction);
     },
     AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {

         var comp1 = component.get("v.wrplst");
         var compJson1 = JSON.stringify(comp1);
         var mapRecords = new Array();
         for (var i = 0; i < comp1.length; i++) {
             mapRecords.push(comp1[i]);
         }
         var len = mapRecords.length;
         var newlen = len + 1;
         var addAction = component.get("c.addRow");
         addAction.setParams({
             "wrapval": compJson1,
             "counterval": newlen,
         });
         addAction.setCallback(this, function(res) {
             var state = res.getState();
             if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                 component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue()));
             } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
                 alert('error');
             } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
                 alert('incompltete');
             }
         });
         $A.enqueueAction(addAction);
     },
     saveRow: function(component, event, helper) {
         var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
         alert('Id value ::::' + Idx);
         var com = component.get("v.wrplst");
         var comJson = JSON.stringify(com);
         var saveAction = component.get("c.saveCall");
         saveAction.setParams({
             "wrvalue": comJson,
             "id": Idx,
         });
         saveAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
             var state = re.getState();
             if (state === 'SUCCESS') {

             }
         });
         $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
     }
 });
```

**Helper**

```
({
    pageLoad: function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.pageLoading");
        var self = this;
        var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
        action.setParams({
            "id": Idx
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(g) {
            var state = g.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {

                component.set("v.wrplst",JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
                self.Method2(component);

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },
    Method2: function(component, event, helper) {

        var comp = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
        var Id1 = component.get("v.theId");
        var compAction = component.get("c.getComponent");
        compAction.setParams({
            "wrapval":compJson,
            "id": Id1,
        });
        compAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state ==='SUCCESS') {
                alert('sucesss');
                var obj=re.getReturnValue();
                alert('obj values:::::'+obj);

                var objs= JSON.parse(obj);
                alert('objs value ::::'+objs);
                console.log('::::::::objs value::::'+objs);
                var s=objs.Components1;
                alert('s value:::::'+s);
                var myJSON2 = JSON.stringify(objs.Components1);
                alert('myJSON2 values :::::'+myJSON2);
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(myJSON2);
                var compo=[];
                var compos=[];
                if(jsonData.length!=null && jsonData.length>0){
                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) 
                    {

                        var counter = jsonData[i].label;
                        alert(counter);

                        compo.push({ value:counter, label:counter });
                    }
                    component.set("v.Components1",compo);
                    alert('components 1 value ::::::'+compo);
                    }
                var myJSON3 = JSON.stringify(objs.Components);
                var jsonData1 = JSON.parse(myJSON3);
                 if(jsonData1.length!=null && jsonData1.length>0){
                for (var i = 0; i <jsonData1.length; i++) 
                {
                    var counter = jsonData1[i].label;
                    compos.push({ value:counter, label:counter });
               } 
                alert('components  value:::::::::::::'+compos);

                component.set("v.Components",compos);
                 }
            }
            else if(state==='error'){
                alert('error value');
            }
                else if(state==='INCOMPLETE'){
                    alert('incomplete values:::');

                }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(compAction);

        },
    componentVal:function(component,event,helper){
        var action=component.get("c.ObjectNames");
        action.setCallback(this,function(re){
            var state=re.getState();
            if(state==='SUCCESS'){

                component.set("v.options",JSON.parse(re.getReturnValue()));
            }
            else if(state==='Error'){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**NewAction**

```
<aura:component controller="ActionController" >
    <aura:attribute name="wrp" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="idval" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute required="true" name="options" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Components" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Components1" type="List"/>

    <aura:attribute required="true" name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="wpchange" type="List" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="deleteJob" type="c:deleteJobEvt"/>

    <tr>
        <td class="cell" style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
            <p >
                <button type="button" onclick="{!c.RemoveClick}" >remove</button>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell" >
            <p>
              <lightning:select name="mySelect" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme}" aura:id="obc" onchange="{!c.dosomething}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
                    <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select> 
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell" >

            <p>
                <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.Operator}">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Pay_Element_Master__c',
                                     v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='CTC_Master__c', 
                                     v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Section_Master__c')}">
                        <option value="None">None</option>
                    </aura:if>

                    <aura:if isTrue="{!(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='CTC_Master__c')}">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.Components}" var="it">
                            <option text="{!it.label}" value="{!it.value}" selected="{!it.selected}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </aura:if>

                    <aura:if isTrue="{!(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Pay_Element_Master__c')}">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.Components1}" var="its">
                            <option text="{!its.label}" value="{!its.value}"  selected="{!its.selected}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </aura:if>
                </lightning:select>
            </p>

        </td>

        <td class="cell" >
            <p>
                <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.Operator}">
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="+ Addition">+ Addition</option>
                    <option value="- Subtract  ">- Subtract</option>
                    <option value="* Multiply ">* Multiply</option>
                    <option value="/ Divide">/ Divide</option>
                </lightning:select>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell" >
            <p>
                <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.SpecialOperator}">
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="*">*</option>
                    <option value="*/">*/</option>
                    <option value="/">/</option>
                </lightning:select>
            </p>
        </td>

        <td class="cell"  style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
            <p>
                <ui:inputText value="{!v.wrp.specialOperatorValue}"/>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell"  style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
            <p>
                <ui:inputText value="{!v.wrp.specialOperatorSlashValue}"/>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</aura:component>
```

**Javascript**

```
({
    RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {

        var event1 = component.getEvent("deleteJob");

        event1.setParams({
            'selectedJob': component.get("v.wrp"),
        });
        event1.fire();
    },
    dosomething: function(component, event, helper) {
        var x = component.find("obc").get("v.value");
        alert('x value::::' + x);
        var comp = component.get("v.wrp");
        var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
        alert('compJson val ::::' + compJson);
        var Id1 = component.get("v.idval");
        alert('Id1 val::::::' + Id1);

        var Action = component.get("c.getComponent");
        Action.setParams({
            "wrapval": compJson,
            "id": Id1,
        });
        Action.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
                var obj = re.getReturnValue();
                var objs = JSON.parse(obj);
                var s = objs.Components1;
                var myJSON2 = JSON.stringify(objs.Components1);
                var myJSON3 = JSON.stringify(objs.Components);
                var compo = [];
                var compos = [];

                alert('myJSON2 values :::::' + myJSON2);
                alert('myJSON3 values :::::' + myJSON3);


                if (myJSON2 != null && jsonData.length!=0 && jsonData.length!=null ) {
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(myJSON2);
                    var lenval = jsonData.length;
                    alert('lenval :::::' + lenval);
                    for (var i = 0; i<lenval; i++) {
                        alert('pay element is calling::::');
                        var counter = jsonData[i].label;
                        compo.push({
                            value: counter,
                            label: counter
                        });
                    }
                    component.set("v.Components1", compo); //this line shows error
                }

                if (myJSON3 != null && jsonData1.length!=0 && jsonData1.length!=null) {
                    var jsonData1 = JSON.parse(myJSON3);
                    var compLen = jsonData1.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i <jsonData1.length;i++) {
                        var counter = jsonData1[i].label;
                        compos.push({
                            value: counter,
                            label: counter
                        });
                    }
                    alert('components  value:::::::::::::' + compos);
                }
                component.set("v.Components", compos);//this line shows error
            }
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(Action);
    }
    })
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56590/discussion-on-question-by-annappa-ph-onchange-functionality-isnt-working-user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set parent component variable in child helper.js. you need to use event something like this ->
create event

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT"> 
<aura:attribute name="attributeValue" type="String"/> 
<aura:attribute name="attributeName" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

register that event in your child component

```
<aura:registerEvent name="setAttribute" type="c:setAttributeEvent"/>
```

and in your dosomething method set the value to the event attributes

```
var setEvent = component.getEvent("setAttribute");   
                    setEvent.setParams({
                        "attributeValue":JSON.stringify(compo),
                        "attributeName": 'Components1'
                    }); 
                    setEvent.fire();
```

then write a handler in your parent component to set the variable.

```
<aura:handler name="setAttribute" event="c:setAttributeEvent" action="{!c.setAttributeValue}"/>
```

define `setAttributeValue`to set the variable values in parent controllerjs.

```
setAttributeValue: function(component, event, helper) 
    { 
        var eventValue= JSON.parse(event.getParam("attributeValue"));
        var name = event.getParam("attributeName");
        alert(name);
         if(name == 'Components')
          component.set("v.Components", eventValue);
        else if(name == 'Components1')
          component.set("v.Components1", eventValue);  

    }
```